# Wordpress Post Grid

Tags: posts

I am trying to make a custom grid for my Wordpress posts. I have been searching the web however all the tutorials I have found utilize a column method where it just alternates between the columns. For what I am doing that would be impossible I need it to actually count off six thumbnails and then return a line and do it again. Does anyone know of a good tutorial/example of this(It can't be a plugin.)? All answers much appreciated. The code below is what I have so war without it wrapping the lines.

[image]

```
 $categories =  get_categories('child_of=2');  
foreach  ($categories as $category) {


        //Display the sub category information using $category values like $category->cat_name
        echo '<h2>'.$category->name.'</h2>';

        foreach (get_posts('cat='.$category->term_id) as $post) {


            echo '<li class="item">';

            setup_postdata( $post );
            $custom = get_field('face');
  echo wp_get_attachment_image($custom);

  echo '<div class="name">';
 $custom = get_field('fullname');
  echo $custom;
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</li>';
```

REVISED TO POST BELLOW:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Wordpress related question, and you can get your desired result by a simple PHP loop:

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($array as $var) {
    if ($i==7) {
        // six items already displayed. 

        // Do whatever you want here 

        // now restart the count
        $i = 1;
    }

    // display your thumbs or whatever

    // increment $i
    $i++
}
```

Comment: how do i get the css to make it go down a line?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are looking to do. Maybe show us an illustration of what you want to achieve?

Comment: i updated my post

Comment: No need to restart counts. PHP features a [modulus operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), as does pretty much every programming language, but Assembler.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be somewhat lengthy. And I'm inclined to call the issue [*off-topic*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the first place, since you have the WP-specific part figured out already.
But since I have a decent grid lying around and my football club just played well, here you are:

### The CSS

```
div.grid-row {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1140px; // adjust to your liking
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.column,
div.splitcol  {
    margin-right: 3.8%;
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
}
div.column {
    width: 30.75%;
}
.ie div.column { // width for IE (I use modernizr)
    width: 30.6%;
}
div.splitcol {
    width: 43.8%;
    margin-right: 12.35%;
}
div.last {
    margin-right: 0;
}
/* collapse columns at some threshold */
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 799px) { // adjust to your liking
    div.column {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
        margin-right: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
/* further collapse splitcols at some threshold */
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 479px) { // adjust to your liking
    div.splitcol {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
        margin-right: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

### Your code adapted / The HTML

```
$categories = get_categories( 'child_of=2' );  
foreach  ( $categories as $category ) {

    echo '<div class="grid-row"><h2>'.$category->name.'</h2></div>';

    $cat_posts = get_posts( 'cat='.$category->term_id );
    $end = count( $cat_posts ) - 1;
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $cat_posts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        $face = get_field( 'face' );
        $name = get_field( 'fullname' );

        if ( $i % 6 === 0 ) {
            echo '<div class="grid-row">';
        }
        if ( $i % 2 === 0 ) {
            echo '<div class="column';
            if ( $i % 6 === 4 ) {
                echo ' last';
            }
            echo '">';
        }
        echo '<div class="splitcol';
        if ( $i % 2 === 1 ) {
            echo ' last';
        }
        echo '">';

        echo wp_get_attachment_image($face)
            . '<div class="name">'.$name.'</div>';

        echo '</div>';
        if ( $i % 2 === 1 ) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
        if ( $i % 6 === 5 ) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
        if ( $i === $end &&  $i % 6 !== 5 ) {
            echo '</div>';
            if ( $i % 2 !== 1 ) {
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

### Alternatives

As foreseen, turned out quite lengthy. The CSS however is adjusted to your requirement of 6 columns. In case you care to dive into it, [here](http://pastebin.com/a0njGavR) is the CSS of the grid I currently use in production in its entirety.

Further you could consider:

- [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)
- [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)
- CSS3 Vodoo using [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count) and [`column-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap) ([related article](http://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/))

Comment: this unfortunately didn't work if u look at my revised image above

Comment: I re-checked the above and changed one integer. That's it though, this should be functional. It might not work completely out-of-the-box with the rest of the CSS you are currently applying, but the grid I gave you is rock-solid, responsive & collapseable. Also note I didn't (and cannot) test your initial code. Try it with static HTML. Sorry, can't elaborate more. This should suffice to get you started.

Comment: what value in the css adjusts the padding/space so i can spread them out more?

Comment: If you want to increase vertical spacing, bottom margin on the `.splitcol` is the simplest. As for horizontal spacing: You can muck around with `padding` as much as you want, but you should not touch the left and right margins. If you alter the `3.8%` (and `12.35%`, respectively) right margin this entire thing's gonna break. All the percentage values are carefully adjusted.

Comment: if u see above its overlapping half way so maybe padding?

Comment: [This](http://pool.tramprennen.org/grid) is what it should look and function like. Good luck with your endeavour!